# create unique Textboxes's control names

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to create unique Textboxes control names for later use, i.e., assign corresponding values from datatables to each of textboxes. I have 128 questions of a survey in a datatable that are divided into group. For example, ABgroup.count = 4 meaning there are 4 questions for group AM. ACgroup.count = 18 and so on with total of 128 rows. Questions are categories into L (likeness), Y (yes/no), or C (comment). L has 4 possibilities of votes (strongly agree, agree, disagree, strongly disagree). I plan to create textboxes control name for AM group as following

```
datatable.count = 4
Q1: txtbx1.Name = AM100
L type: txtbx2.Name = AM100a; txtbx3.Name = AM100b; txtbx3.Name = AM100c; txtbx5.Name = AM100d
Q2: txtbox6.Name = AM101
Y type: txtbx7.Name = AM101y; txtbx8.Name = AM101n
Q3: similar as Q1
Q4 / C type: txtbx13.Name = AM103c
```

My question should I create textboxes controls separately for each group as described above? Or create something that dynamically create all textboxes control names? either way, can you please show me how to achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: what does the name matter?  you might explain why you think it is important or how you plan to use them by name.

Comment: Well, don't assign the Name property at all, problem solved.  It is completely unclear why you think you need to use it.  It is only really useful in the designer, it sets the name of the backing variable, but clearly you don't want to use it.

Comment: If you are using WPF or ASP use data binding. Do not create them all, let the framework do that for you.

Comment: Good question. The reason I think about assign names is because later I want to know which vote goes to which textbox. I will need to calculate the total votes of L type, i.e., total of strongly agree goes to which textbox and so on. That for group AM only. If there are 11 groups then how can I know to assign total votes to a specific textboxes?

Comment: I am also supposed to create textboxes dynamically. Please tell me if it's a bad idea or not

Comment: Since you're creating everything dynamically you can simply add the references to the controls to whatever structures you like so they can be associated with each other at a later time.  This could be as simple as Lists, or more complicated like a custom Class that holds multiple Lists/References within, etc...

Comment: Idle_Mind: can you please show me an example or two how to do it in Lists? Thanks in advance